# The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x a.deb && apt-get install a.deb' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been trying to write a dockerfile for a .deb file. This is what I've written so far:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /invisily

COPY . ./

USER root
RUN chmod +x a.deb && \
    apt-get install a.deb
```

All the phases run fine but i get an error at the end saying:

```
Need to get 79.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 296 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x a.deb &&     apt-get install a.deb' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `-y` in your `apt-get` command to auto-accept confirmation questions and run non-interactively.

As you can see from the log, `apt-get` is asking the user a question (expects a Y/N answer via keyboard), but since there is no interactivity with a user, it gets aborted.